# Casting from int to parameterized-width logic

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Given the parameters

```
parameter int eC,
parameter int cntW = ...
```

I have the following assignment:

```
logic [cntW-1:0] count;
logic [cntW-1:0] front;
logic [cntW-1:0] back;
assign count = condition ? front : back+eC+1 - front;
```

where `back+eC+1 - front` is promoted to a 32 bit `int`, which is wider than `cntW`.
How can I explicitly cast `int` to the variable width `cntW` to suppress the warning that comes from the implicit conversion?

The warning is

```
Continuous assignment width mismatch
  5 bits (lhs) versus 32 bits (rhs).
  Source info: assign count = ((back >= front) ? (back - front) : (((back + 
  eC) + 1) - front));
```

Comment: How are `back` and `front` declared? Show us the complete warning.

Comment: I added the declarations of front and back and the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the bare number `1` is implicitly a 32-bit signed decimal value.  Operands in arithmetic expression get extended to the width of the largest operand before applying the operators. You can use `1'b1` which is an explicit 1-bit value. Also declare eC with the same width as the other variables

```
typedef logic [cntW-1:0] cnt_t;
parameter cnt_t eC;

cnt_t count;
cnt_t front;
cnt_t back;
assign count = condition ? front : back+eC+1'b1 - front;
```

Another thing you do is use a cast

```
assign count = condition ? front : cntW'(back+eC+1) - front;
```